# dropdown option tag constantly replicating previous row qty value in for loop

Tags: php, html

I would need some assistance on the below problem:

I'm trying to display qty value from db via option tag, but the option tag keeps adding on previous row value onto subsequent option tag row value. Would appreciate any advice/solution on this, thanks.

```
$arrayqty = $_SESSION['pqty'];

<div id='qty'>

    <?php

    $options = array();
    $options[] = "<option value=''></option>";

    foreach($arrayqty as $qty )
    {        
        $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE qty = '$qty'"); 

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

        $nqty = $row['qty']; 

        for($x=1; $x<=$nqty; $x++)
        {

            $options[] = "<option value='{$x}'>{$x}</option>";
        }
        ?>

        <select class="list" >
            <?php echo implode( $options); ?>
        </select>

        <?php
    }

    ?>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `foreach` after `echo implode( $options);` use:

```
unset($options);
```

Or if you want to keep the empty option try this

```
$options = array();
$options[] = "<option value=''></option>";
```

Comment: but then he will not have an empty option on the subsequent selects

Comment: @user3379528 dont forget to upvote / accept if this solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your `$options` array inside of your foreach loop.

```
foreach($arrayqty as $qty ) {        

    $options = array();
    $options[] = "<option value=''></option>";
```